# Join query is taking more time

Tags: mysql, join

My Query is taking more time to give an output, can I create query that can be give easy output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(property.Project_Name), property.Property_Type, ROUND(AVG(property.Unit_Price_psf)), property.Transacted_Price
FROM property
JOIN avg_property
WHERE avg_property.Project_Name=property.Project_Name
AND avg_property.Median_Price BETWEEN '$mdpr1' AND '$mdpr2'
GROUP BY property.Project_Name
```

Comment: Do you have an index on avg_property.Median_Price field?

Comment: we need more information, table structure, execute the explain command

Comment: For debuging, it would help if we could have the output of whous 3 querys: "SHOW CREATE TABLE property;", "SHOW CREATE TABLE avg_property;" and "DESCRIBE SELECT ..."

Comment: Yes I have index on avg_property.Median_Price field.\

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the alternative of distinct

```
SELECT
  property.Project_Name,
  property.Property_Type,
  ROUND(AVG(property.Unit_Price_psf)),
  property.Transacted_Price
FROM property
  JOIN avg_property
WHERE exists(select
           Project_Name
         from property
         group by Project_Name)
    and avg_property.Project_Name = property.Project_Name
    AND avg_property.Median_Price BETWEEN '$mdpr1'
    AND '$mdpr2'
GROUP BY property.Project_Name
```

Comment: I want to use unique Project_Name from the database that's why I have write distinct , any alternative you have?

Comment: this is the alternative of distinct. if you have project_name field in your table it should be unique . duplicates should not be allowed.

Comment: No I have duplicate entry for  project name and I want to check in those entry,